# Broken package problem installing ring on Mint 18.1

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management, aptitude, voip

I have a Linux Mint 18.1 Serena installed, and the `apt-get install ring` won't do the trick. it returns the following:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ring : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.17) but it is not installable
        Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is to be installed
        Depends: ring-daemon (= 20161228.1.49686a5~dfsg1-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[image]

Then I tried:

```
apt-get clean & update
aptitude -f install ring
apt-get install ring --fix-broken
```

But, it didn't help to resolve this problem. How to solve?

The output of `apt-cache policy ring`:

```
ring:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20161228.1.49686a5~dfsg1-1
  Version table:
     20161228.1.49686a5~dfsg1-1 500
        500 https://dl.ring.cx/ring-nightly/ubuntu_16.10 ring/main amd64 Packages
```

`sudo aptitude`:

[image]

Comment: [don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy ring`? (as text please)

Comment: @xhienne, I have added the output of apt-get cache policy

Comment: @GaniRakhmatov Thanks, that helped a lot, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this announcement](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/12/linux-mint-18-1-released), "Linux Mint 18.1 is supported until 2021 and is based on Ubuntu **16.04** LTS".

Judging by the result of your `apt-cache policy ring` command, your `ring` package was built for Ubuntu **16.10**. This is no surprise then that some dependencies to `ring` are missing on your system (or, rather, are available but not with the expected version).

The solution is to install `ring` for Ubuntu 16.04. You must modify the ring repositories you have set up, by changing `https://dl.ring.cx/ring-nightly/ubuntu_16.10` to `https://dl.ring.cx/ring-nightly/ubuntu_16.04`

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems when installing packages with apt-get. Try with aptitude

```
sudo aptutude
```

Then search your package (typing "/") and try to install it. aptitude usually offers more solutions when there is a problem with the instalation or the dependencies.